# Android - Can an app listen for an event fired by another app?

Tags: android

My exact scenario is:

User copies text in Chrome or another app, for example, and I want my app to react on this event.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to changes to the clipboard via `ClipboardManager`. If you need some other app-specific event, the other app would need to expose a Service or send a broadcast to notify listeners.

Comment: Cheers for that mate. Do I have to keep my app alive though... is it not gonna die when goes in background?

Comment: You can start a Service to keep listening for callbacks. If you're using broadcasts, they will restart your app to deliver themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you add an intent filter to your app and if chrome or the other app broadcastes an intent .